# ORA-00904 'invalide indentifier' error when using 'MERGE INTO' with parameterized query

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I don't know why this is happening but I am trying to use a parameterized query in order to execute a merge

If I run the query with hardcoded values the query runs fine:

```
MERGE INTO MyTable e
USING (with cte(id, name,date) as
(select * from (select 10,'Tester','2013-05-08' from dual union
select 11,'Tester2','2015-05-08' from dual union
select 12,'Tester3'','2015-05-09' from dual union
select 13,'Tester4'','2015-05-09' from dual
))select * from cte) S
ON (e.id = S.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET prefixName = S.name,lastModi=S.date
```

However when I execute this parameterized query and when I assign the appropriate values I'm getting an ORA-00904 error in the date1 column

```
MERGE INTO MyTable e  
USING (with cte(id, name,date) as
(select * from (select :id1,:name1,:date1 from dual union
select :id2,:name2,:date2 from dual union
select :id3,:name3,:date3 from dual union
select :id4,:name4,:date4 from dual
)) select * from cte) S
ON (e.id = S.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET prefixName = S.name,lastModi=S.date
```

Can someone helps me with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Based on the documentation it expects a field name there. Could you please try me alias that expression? Or create something more expression like? For example: `''||:date1 as datefield` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some investigation about the issue and it seems to be a DB link issue. For some reasons when we put parameters in the query, Oracle is not able to found the table because it's not in the correct database. However with hardcoded values in the query it success to find the table even it's on another database. So I changed the database in my code and now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I just tested, and the first query does **not** run fine, it throws the same error. This is because you can't use the reserved keyword "date" as a column alias. Change it to "date_" or something like that, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When **forced** to use an Oracle reserved keyword, you must double-quote it:

```
MERGE INTO MyTable e  
USING (
  with cte(id, name,"date") as
    (select * from (select :id1,:name1,:date1 from dual union
     select :id2,:name2,:date2 from dual union
     select :id3,:name3,:date3 from dual union
     select :id4,:name4,:date4 from dual
    )
  ) select * from cte) S
ON (e.id = S.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET prefixName = S.name,lastModi=S."date"
```

The best is not to use reserved keywords at all: `the_spec_date` instead of `date`:

```
MERGE INTO MyTable e  
USING (
  with cte(id, name,the_spec_date) as
    (select * from (select :id1,:name1,:date1 from dual union
     select :id2,:name2,:date2 from dual union
     select :id3,:name3,:date3 from dual union
     select :id4,:name4,:date4 from dual
    )
  ) select * from cte) S
ON (e.id = S.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET prefixName = S.name,lastModi=S.the_spec_date
```